# GSEA results plot interpretation

Tags: gsea

I need to plot the results of a GSEA analysis we performed on scRNA data. I am stumbling upon various possibilities for this and sometimes I am struggling a bit to understand how to interpret it. My source is this: https://yulab-smu.top/biomedical-knowledge-mining-book/enrichplot.html

Specifically, in the DotPlot the x axis is geneRatio, in my results table there is no metric called that way, how is it computed? Another question is regarding the ridge plot, the way it is defined is: "The ridgeplot will visualize expression distributions of core enriched genes" This is a bit oscure to me, and in the plot that I generated from my data following that tutoria the x axis is automatically labelled as "enrichment distribution" which in my understanding has a completely different meaning in this case.

Ihave an object of this class: https://rdrr.io/bioc/DOSE/man/gseaResult-class.html, that now I just fed to the functions as explained in that tutorial. The fields of the result table are:

`ID     Description setSize enrichmentScore NES pvalue  p.adjust    qvalue  rank    leading_edge    core_enrichment`

I don't find any info on how these results are used, I don't know if showing values or plots may be useful as I have more of a methodological doubt.

My question is, if I needed to build these plots on my own without relying on the library documented in the website, starting from the output of cluster profiler, how would I do it? I don't need R code but an understanding of what is done.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Hi, it would help if we can see the results table you have. The geneRatio is a measure calculated by clusterProfiler about the number of genes of the gene set found vs those in the gene set.